# Braided stainless steel water supply hoses versus rubber hoses

Tags: plumbing, faucet, water-pressure, hose, cistern

I've noticed some apartments that use both for water supply to faucets and toilet cisterns.

I understand that the braided hoses are rated for higher pressures, but how do they compare in terms of durability at typical static and dynamic pressures?

Is it correct to consider the EPDM layer in braided hoses, by itself (minus the support of the stainless steel braiding), to be equivalent to a rubber hose in terms of pressure resistance?

Comment: Supposedly stainless steel braided hoses are less likely to break/rupture. But that depends on the quality of the hose itself. I also don't think your question is answerable because there are far too many variables to consider.

Comment: The only supply connection that every leaked for me was braided stainless. Fortunately it was a very fast drip :not a burst, as in was in an attic ; I heard it dripping and was able to shut off the valve. It was about 2 years old . I went with corrogated/flexible copper on the next water heater.

Answer (score 1):

The braided stainless steel flex supply lines are just *jacketed* with braided stainless. The jacket is there for appearance and perhaps resistance to incidental contact damage, but has nothing to do with the pressure rating.

In general, *rubber* hose is not used for faucets and cisterns; the hoses (whether jacketed with braided stainless or not) are commonly reinforced PVC (at least in my area, anyway). The washers are often EDPM rubber...

Comment: The braided ss armored lines are probably more resistant to rodent damage than the black rubber ones. Some of the ss armored ones have an automatic shut-off valve which closes in the event of a full on leak. The downside of these is that they work by using a flow restrictor  (in the washer end I think) which increases the fill time for clothes washers and maybe toilets.  In the event of a rupture a valve in the supply end closes and shuts off the flow until it's reset.